# ReferenceError: targetsheetByName is not defined // GoogleSheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have assign this script in an image in my sheet so when i click it, to automatically the script running and transfer the data of a specific row to another tab of my spreadsheed.

**I want to transfer the data of the row A2:S2 from the same spreadheet. From the tab Submit0 to the tab FUTURE.**

**the script i use is this:**

```
function CopyRowstocks()
 {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  let sourcedata = ss.getSheetByName("Submit0")
  let targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("FUTURE");

  let sourcerange = sourcedata.getRange("A2:S2");
  let sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

  let lastrow = targetsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  sourcerange.copyTo(targetsheet.getRange(lastrow,1))

 
}
```

But whenever i try to run this script it show me this message:

> ReferenceError: targetsheetByName is not defined
> [image: error]

Why is appearing this meesage? What mistake do i have done?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Code is executing successfully for me. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, so this can be troubleshot?

Comment: i solved it after all! it was a very stupit mistake. Insstead of "FUTURE" Ι was writing "FUTURE "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after all! it was a very stupit mistake. Insstead of "FUTURE" Ι was writing "FUTURE "